# Reducing the surface integral of the unit normal to a contour integral

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, contour-integration

Given a two-dimensional patch S with boundary L, the integral of the unit normal $\vec{N}$ over S can be reduced to a contour integral over the boundary L. (The resulting identity is in the comments.) Can someone point to a textbook where this is mentioned or appears as an exercise as Professor Shifrin indicated in the comments?

Comment: Not in textbooks, but here’s a hint. Do it component by component and apply Stokes’s Theorem. For example, is $\vec i$ the curl of a nice vector field?

Comment: Thanks! Can the result be found somewhere?

Comment: No. Figure it out for yourself.

Comment: .5 RxT. Trying to figure out whether this is a well-established result.

Comment: What does $T$ mean on the surface? This is an exercise — or a special case of an exercise — that surely  appears in books. Does an exercise make something well-established? Who knows.

Comment: R is the position vector, T is the unit tangent to the boundary. Can't find a textbook with an exercise that asks this question.

Comment: You did not answer my question. You need a vector field defined on the entire surface. Look for Archimedes’s buoyancy principle. It uses the same general result.

Comment: S is a 2D patch, L is its contour boundary. N and R defined on S, T defined on L. 

Integral of N over S   =   .5 * Integral of (R x T) over L

Comment: I know all this, but you need to review Stokes’s Theorem.

Comment: Odd that I already told you this in a post aged ago ….

Comment: It was a different question, but your comment then was equally unhelpful. :)

Comment: Maybe you need to learn more ….